# Run linphone on android simulator - Unable to load optional library ffmpeg-linphone

Tags: android, ffmpeg, simulator, linphone

I success prepare and make build.
 but still no done with deploying on device or simulator.

Run on target 21 .

Error message :

> W/FactoryImpl: Unable to load optional library ffmpeg-linphone:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.linphone-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.linphone-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libffmpeg-linphone.so"
>   A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0xa44d5aba in tid
>   4306 (org.linphone)

Comment: Are you running `make install` with the emulator running?

Comment: No just make than i open project with android studio last version . Small fix and i get all green and build success. linphone sdk uninstall on termination... I see it from run or debug side bar...Maybe in prepare regime i see one msg boost lib missing ( i have installed boost c++ lib)

Comment: If you're installing just the default APK from the codebase, then just run `make install` after `make`. That should deploy the APK automatically. Linphone's build system isn't really suited to Android Studio.

Comment: i will try ... i also setup USB debugger intro simulator os , install almost every platform for emulators. This works fine in Android Studio 2.2 . but i am practice to use updated libs and gui's.

Comment: You can still update the code no problem, it's just the building and deployment process that'll be different to usual.